# Cannot find symbol even when they are in the same package

Tags: cannot-find-symbol

I trying to compile and execute a CarroTestar.java file where main is contained. I create too a Carro.java file in the same package what i call aula1. But i receive the following error when i try:

```
.\CarroTestar.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Carro c1 = new Carro(null);
        ^
  symbol:   class Carro
  location: class CarroTestar
.\CarroTestar.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        Carro c1 = new Carro(null);
                       ^
  symbol:   class Carro
  location: class CarroTestar
2 errors
```

I import the package in both files using `package aula1;`

What can i do? (Sorry for my english)

I trying to compile and execute my file and should print "bibibi" in terminal.